# What do the diseased bodies in Act II do?

Tags: diablo-iii

In the sewers and water ways of Act II there are piles of diseased bodies that have health, but don't seem to be doing anything except for lying there waiting to be destroyed. Can they hurt me in any way, or are they just a barrel with a health bar?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can spew a poison cloud when 'killed', and sometimes I think they spawn Accursed or other poisonous guys as well (similar to Grotesque mobs)

Comment: source? 15 chars

Comment: Personal experience. They don't do much in normal, but they tend to spew them out pretty quickly in higher difficulties. There's also an event tied to these piles as well which will spawn a unique Accursed at the end. Also, the ones just before breaking the jeweller out of the barrel do spawn them pretty well even in normal. I've only seen them spawn Accursed though, not grotesque-esque mobs.

Comment: @MatthewScharley I meant that they spawn Accursed, like how Grotesque mobs spawn flies/imps etc. (i.e. they're 'monster containers' of a sort)